# Windows Installer Package builder for .Net application that offers other software downloads

Tags: .net, windows-installer, software-distribution, advanced-installer, packagemaker

I have developed an applications in C# .Net that users can download and use for free.

I need a **Installer Package Builder** that can generate **Installer Package** of my .Net application (*Windows Form and/or WPF*) that also offers the user to download & install 3rd party application along with my application.

(*I have seen several windows applications when we try to install that application its installer offers some other applications to download and install on our system*)

I have searched from google but couldn't find any Installer Builder that offers 3rd party applications for making money.

Answer (score 1):

Both Advanced Installer and InstallShield tools have built-in support to package as many prerequisites (third party softwares) as you want into a suite installation setup.

Here are two articles about how you could use those tools:

[Advanced Installer Suite installation](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html)

[InstallSHield suite installation](https://www.revenera.com/blog/software-installation/installing-a-suite-package-operations/)

Comment: For prerequisites i can u Visual Studio installer.
i'm looking for an installer package generator that offers user to download third party application along with my application.
actually i'm looking for some thing like pay-per-install